# Bookmark onebox is hiding the reply arrow

Tags: bug, chat, onebox, reply, chat-bookmarks

When posting a direct reply in chat, there is an arrow indicating this, which links to the replied message.

However, when [the reply](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4939686#4939686) is a bookmark link, the bookmark onebox is swallowing the arrow:

> [image: onebox of bookmark without reply arrow]

To prove this is a reply, here is screenshot of the edit mode:

> [image: source of the message showing it is a reply]

Can this please be fixed? I'm pretty sure it used to be fine before the recent chat design change.