# Bounty can be started without a reason, while adding a moderator only notice in revisions

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, revisions-list, hacked

I noticed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252623/i-improved-an-edit-but-did-i-actually) that a fresh bounty has been started without a notice, and suspected I know how it was done.

It was easy enough to reproduce on [one of my questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279612/bookmark-onebox-is-hiding-the-reply-arrow):

> [image: a notice-less bounty]

No reason is displayed, and  even worse, the [revisions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/279612/revisions) is showing a moderator only notice, "Content dispute":

> [image: revisions list with the sudden "content dispute" entry]

Can this please be fixed so that bounty reason must be given and validated server side?

<sub>(Using the [hacked](/questions/tagged/hacked) tag since adding that moderator only notice is kind of a hack)</sub>

Comment: OK. Tell me what you did. Nownownownownownownownow!

Comment: @TIPS hmm.... nah, better not litter poor MSE with hacked moderator notices... ;-)

Comment: I'm kidding @Sha. Jokes on anyone who re-tries this since it's most probably rep Gone with The Wind.

Comment: Lol, but you have definitely chosen some specific notice id, they are not random.

Comment: @TIPS lol no worry, and I actually wanted to bountify that question for a while, just forgot about it. :D

Comment: @nicael I had no idea what the value means, now I know... and still wonder how you made yours totally blank. (Got 404 when trying)

Comment: @nicael no custom request, just tweaking existing data.

Comment: I guess you can pick post notice id's  from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252633/in-the-posthistory-table-what-is-that-number-in-the-comment-column)

Comment: @rene Wait, why only 33 and 34 there, what did I misunderstood? The notice for the bounties have ids of 10-15.

Comment: That might be true @nicael but the post notice is a different history record, hence different id's

Comment: @rene Don't you know where could I get the ids with corresponding names?

Comment: Nope, not all the types tables are public I'm afraid.

Comment: Huh? Our bounties got refunded. But yours still has notice.

Comment: @rene well, I used 20, which isn't documented.

Comment: @nicael yeah, looks like Geoff removed the bounties in some low level tool (as they're gone without a trace), probably that tool can't handle a non-bounty notice...

Comment: @Sha I've already had an experience with my bounties being removed in such way ;) As for the notice, there's a special entry in the mod menu which allows to remove it. Geoff just didn't use it.

Comment: Lol your bounty gone again :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure enough, there wasn't any proper validation on the notice types when bounties were started.  There is now.

Thanks for the report and I have refunded your bounties.

Comment: You have forgotten to remove that ill notice, and it doesn't even show up properly :)

Comment: @nicael well, always fun to be suddenly reminded of this, no need to remove. ;-)

Comment: @Sha woohoo!!!!